# SQL Server 2008 The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted

Tags: sql-server, transactions, batch-file, triggers

I got this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getManagerSalary 
(
@Emp_id         INT,
@ManagerSalary  MONEY OUTPUT
)
AS
SELECT @ManagerSalary = es.Salary
FROM [outdoorparadise].[dbo].[Employee] AS e 
INNER JOIN 
    [outdoorparadise].[dbo].[Employee] AS m
    ON e.Manager_id = m.Emp_id
INNER JOIN
    [outdoorparadise].[dbo].[Employee_staff] AS es
    ON e.Manager_id = es.Emp_staff_code
WHERE e.Emp_id = @Emp_id;
```

I got this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkSalary ON Employee_staff
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE
    @Emp_id INT,
    @NewSalary MONEY,
    @ManagerSalary MONEY;

    SELECT @NewSalary = Salary
    FROM inserted;

    SELECT @Emp_id = Emp_staff_code
    FROM inserted;

    EXEC getManagerSalary @Emp_id = @Emp_id, 
        @ManagerSalary = @ManagerSalary OUTPUT;

    IF @NewSalary > @ManagerSalary
        BEGIN
        RAISERROR 60000 'Salary cannot be higher than the salary of the manager!'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        END
    ELSE
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

When I update salary to a value higher than the manager's salary I get the raise error + this error: The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

When I try to update the salary to a value lower than the manager's salary I still get this: The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Could someone please tell me how can I fix this problem?
I searched, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks,
Ryuken

PS: This is my first post maybe I didn't paste code the correct way so I'm sorry.

Comment: I need to comment on your trigger - you have made a mistake that would cause problems.Triggers operate on batches in SQl server and you cannot assume that only 1 record will be sent (even if you think that is all that will be sent, it won't hold true over time). You should not be setting a value from inserted to a variable unless it is a table varaible.

Answer (score 3):

Ditch the trigger. Replace it with a check constraint and a scalar function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetManagerSalary(@Emp_id int) RETURNS money
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
        SELECT es.Salary
        FROM [dbo].[Employee] e 
        JOIN [dbo].[Employee] m ON m.Emp_id = e.Manager_id
        JOIN [dbo].[Employee_staff] es ON es.Emp_staff_code = e.Manager_id
        WHERE e.Emp_id = @Emp_id;
END

GO

ALTER TABLE Employee_staff
    ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Salary
    CHECK (ISNULL([Salary], 0) <= ISNULL(dbo.GetManagerSalary([Salary]), 1e9)))
```

Comment: I think in this way, OP do not need to impose validation in trigger, as the constraint is doing everything. That's great +1 for this.

Comment: I'd make sure to test the edge case where the person being inserted is the top level manager.

Comment: @hlgem I thought of that. That's what the ISNULLs and <= are for.

Comment: @ Anthony Faull,I agree it should, I just wanted the OP to know he needed to test that to make sure it worked the way he anticipated. Espcially since he may create a differnt function for some specific business rules he has.